# Google's cache shows a blank page but Fetch as Google shows the content. Can Google index my site?

Tags: seo, fetch-as-google, google-cache, react-js

My site content is loaded by ReactJS by fetching a webservice (in componentDidLoad).

I need a strong SEO positioning on my pages, so I am trying to understand if Googlebot can read the content.

---

**Fetch As Google**
[image: example images]

---

**Page Cache** (show with the Google search resuts)

No content - Empty page

---

Can Google actually fetch and index the content when Fetch As Google shows content but the Google cache does not?  Does Google bot really read my React-loaded HTML?  Do I need to pre-render my pages (i.e. https://prerender.io/)?